# parameter in subclass css for moving text

Tags: css

i'd want move text **"MENU"** inline like **"CONTACTS"** , here image : 
[image]

class to manipulating that, is this piece of css code :

```
.footer .column3.foot-column ul li {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

code html\php :

```
?>
<div class="ma-footer-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="row">
        <div class="f-col f-col61 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="logo-bottom column1 foot-column col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer-column1')->toHtml() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column2 foot-column col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer-column2')->toHtml() ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column3 foot-column col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer-column3')->toHtml() ?>
            </div>
             <div class="column4 foot-column col-md-3 col-xs-12" style="margin: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('footer-column4')->toHtml() ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="back-top" class="hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></div>
```

When i try to change a parameter "float" the text under menu become in this way,  here image :

[image]

Does someone  know if exist some alternative method for resolving this problem? i try with `inline-block` but doesn't work...(i hope this time can be clear the problem.)

Comment: Please also show your HTML. Without that, CSS means nothing.

Comment: Kill the `float`, display each `li` as a `block` and `text-align: center` the content.

Comment: In this way :  .footer .column3.foot-column ul li {
    clear: both;
   **[display: block;]**
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    **[text-align: center;]**                                                                                                }                                                                                                         @UncaughtTypeError

Comment: thanks @UncaughtTypeError ..absolutely work ;)